# DELPHI MessageDlg Call from DLL disrupts Control Focus

Tags: dll, messagebox, delphi-xe8

Recent upgrade to RAD XE8.

I have a dll with several MessageDLg calls e.g. Warning/Information etc e.g.

```
procedure Information(Msg: string); stdcall;
begin
    MessageDlg(Msg,mtInformation, [mbOK],0);
end;
```

I noticed last week the following:-
If I double click on a grid with a handler

```
begin
  Information("I am here"); //in the dll
ens
```

the message is displayed but when I click and the message box disappears I can no longer click on the grid (Mouse wheel does work but not the buttons) (no response). If I click on a second control and then back on the grid all is well again.

I tried adding to the DLL

```
uses VCL.Forms;

procedure Information(Msg: string); stdcall;
begin
  Application.Handle := GetForegroundWindow;
  try
    MessageDlg(Msg,mtInformation, [mbOK],0);
  finally
    Application.Handle := 0;
  end;
end;
```

to no avail.

I have established the following:-

ih my app

```
CanFocus;  //DBGrid1
MessageDlg(Msg,mtInformation, [mbOK],0);
CanFocus;  //Still DBGrid
```

but in my app (calling the MessageDlg in the DLL via the function Information())

```
CanFocus;  //DBGrid1
Information('Hi ya');
CanFocus;  //MAINFORM
```

*CanFocus only added for  debug purposes*

So the first dblclick on the DBGrid calls Information but subsequent dblclicks are not detected in the VCL (messages are visible via Windows 
Detective). 
in VC.LDBGids TCustomDBGrid.AcquireFocus: 
Focused is True the first time and False subsequently, until I click a second control and then back on the DBGrid.

Does his make the issue clearer?

TIA

Ephraim

Comment: Is the DLL relevant here. Try to reproduce this issue in a very simple VCL app where all the code resides in the same executable module. Try to cut this down to a trivial reproduction.

Comment: I did. It only occurs with the DLL. Change MessageDlg to Beep; No Issue.

Comment: Changing too Beep proves nothing. Could you produce an MCVE? Otherwise we'll have to try to do so, and in my experience, what often happens then is that the code we produce is actually not the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Setting the global variable `UseLatestCommonDialogs` to `False` solved the problem!

I'm having the same issue and posted a question on Embarcadero Forum. I hope the answer help you:

> That is because none of the HWNDs that belong to the EXE are being
>   used as the owner for the modal dialog window, so it can't restore
>   focus correctly when closed. That is why you have to click on the grid
>   again to regain focus.
>
> Raymond Chen has a whole series of articles on his "Old New Thing"
>   blog on MSDN that discuss issues related to modal window ownership (or
>   lack of).
>
> That is because calling MessageDlg() inside the EXE has access to the
>   EXE's TApplication and TForm HWNDs to use as modal dialog owners. A
>   DLL does not have that same access.
>
> I would suggest getting rid of MessageDlg() inside the DLL altogether.
>   Call the Win32 MessageBox() or TaskDialog() directly instead, then you
>   can provide whatever HWND you need as the owner window.
>
> Remy Lebeau (TeamB)